# Webpack dev server not working (strange page loaded)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I work with web pack and when I try to run the run script (npm run build:dev) i get this weird page with is actually my workspace folders instead the actual website:
[image]

heres my package.json if needed and I used VSCode:

{
"name": "pro-lyrics",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
"build": "webpack",
"start:dev": "webpack serve",
"test": "echo "Error: no test specified" && exit 1"
},
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"devDependencies": {
"webpack": "^5.12.3",
"webpack-cli": "^4.3.1",
"webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.1"
}
}

Answer (score 0):

You need to define where you keep your HTML files in your configuration file for webpack

```
  devServer: {  
    contentBase: './' // this is default main folder
  }
```